# Ethereum fork of OpenBazaar

Tags: dapps, bitcoin, network

Is anyone forking OpenBazaar for Ethereum? [OpenBazaar](https://openbazaar.org/) is a Bitcoin marketplace, and the OpenBazaar developers have expressed no interest to integrate any currencies other than Bitcoin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep an eye on [Safemarket.io](http://safemarket.io): it is already deployed live on the Frontier network.

See [getting started](https://github.com/SafeMarket/dapp/wiki/Getting-Started) and [releases](https://github.com/SafeMarket/dapp/releases).

Open source at https://github.com/safemarket

Subreddit at https://reddit.com/r/safemarket

Comment: Works fine for me and it redirects to https://safemarket.github.io...

Comment: So it looks like they haven't setup HTTPS on safemarket.io :(  So for now the HTTPS link doesn't work.  I am not sure if it should be edited away to http, since really the HTTPS link should work eventually...

Answer (score 3):

No. This wont easily happen.

It's not really possible to fork OpenBazaar to work with Ethereum, as very basic design principles of OpenBazaar work based on the Bitcoin *pay to script hash* (P2SH) multisignature and escrow accounts.

To port OpenBazaar to work with Ethereum style smart contracts it would probably be easier to start from scratch. As other answers in this thread pointed out there are already such initiatives.

Comment: Multisig escrow accounts are easy to do with Ethereum, if not easier than with Bitcoin.

Comment: That's not what I said. I said the design of bitcoin's p2sh does not really match ethereums contracts and therefore the key functionality of openbazaar is not compatible with ethereum.

Comment: The multisignature and escrow accounts implementation with P2SH is mostly independent of the rest of the OpenBazaar design and can easily be replaced with an Ethereum implementation.